# I need to add a webform block in drupal 7 for a custom theme

Tags: drupal-7

I need to add a webform as a block to a page or view in Drupal 7, the problem is that the theme is customized and only has about 2 regions, but when I add the block to one of those regions the data comes out disorganized and not where I want. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwxSr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p12uL.png)

I would like to know if any of you have knowledge of how I could add the webform in the section that I need with that topic that is already defined in the company where I work.